# Sharpening a portrait with PS Elements

Tags: photoshop, portrait, sharpening, photoshop-elements

I realise there are a thousand and one ways (maybe a little over the top) of sharpening an image in full blown photoshop, however these appear to require features not within Photoshop Elements.

Has anyone had an good experience with sharpening that would be applicable to what PSE is capable of ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not wrong about there being a thousand and one ways!

My personal favourite is to use a high pass filter. Duplicate your image (or duplicate everything and merge it into one layer if you're using layers) and put that layer on top. Then you go to filters>Other>high pass, and then set that to something around 2 to 5 pixels. Basically you just want to see the edges of your image, it's kind of a taste thing. The value will also vary depending on how large your image is (more pixels generally requires higher numbers)

Then take your horrible weird looking grey layer and change the blending mode to overlay. You can leave it there, or if you feel the effect is a little strong (which is often the case) simply lower the opacity on your high pass layer to taste.

Answer (score 1):

To sharpen an image in PSE:

Choose Enhance > Adjust Sharpness.
Select Preview check box.
Set any of the following options to sharpen your image, and then click OK. Amount. Sets the amount of sharpening.

This always does the trick, and it's easy and simple.

For details see this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvkMGzIWvoU